# The measurability of convolution in locally compact group

Tags: measure-theory, fourier-analysis, convolution, harmonic-analysis, locally-compact-groups

Prove or disprove:

Let $G$ be a locally compact Hausdorff topological group and $\mu$ be a left haar measure on $G$. $f\in L^1(G,\mu)$, $g\in L^{\infty}(G,\mu)$. Then $f*g$ is measurable with respect of $(G,\mu)$.

(I can prove it when $(G,\mu)$ is $\sigma$-finite. But I don't know if it is true when $(G,\mu)$ isn't $\sigma$-finite.)

Comment: But I can't prove the new measure ($\nu$) is regular, then I can't get the regular Borel product of $\nu$ and $\nu$.(Because I want to use the proposition which is similar to Fubini theorem to prove $t\rightarrow\int g(s^{-1}t)\,\mathrm{d}\nu(s)$ is measurable. (c.f.\ Measure Theory- Second Edition, Donald L. Cohn, Theorem 7.6.7))
If I do it directly, I can't prove it even if when $g$ is the character function.

Comment: I can't use Fubini theorem directly because I can't prove that $(s,t)\rightarrow g(s^{-1}t)$ is measurable with respect of the product measure. The ``regular Borel product" of two regular Borel measure may not equal to the product measure (we use this product measure for Fubini theorem) of them. We can prove $(s,t)\rightarrow g(s^{-1}t)$ is measurable with respect of the regular Borel product of a regular Borel measure and itself. Then we can use a theorem which is similar to Fubini theorem. (c.f.\ Measure Theory- Second Edition, Donald L. Cohn, the last paragraph of page 222))

Comment: I still can't prove $f\mathrm{d}\mu$ is regular. Could you give me more hints? Or which book gives a proof of it? But $K_1\subset K_2...$ isn't ture. I can give you a countexample: $G=(\mathbb{R},+)$, $\mu$ is the left haar measure on it. $K_n=[0,n]$, $A=\mathbb{R}$, $f=e^{-|x|}$

Comment: Then you get $g$ is measurable with respect of $(G\times G, B(G\times G))$, not $(G\times G, B(G)\times B(G))$. They may be different and we have $B(G)\times B(G) \subset B(G\times G)$. ($B(G)$ consists of all the Borel sets of $G$)

Comment: It's $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f$, not $\int_{0}^{\infty}f$

Comment: ohh, yeah i see your counterexample now. my bad

Comment: We have counterexample which tells us that $B(G)\times B(G) = B(G\times G)$ may not ture.

Comment: Yes. It is made by the usual method to get the product measure space.

Comment: Ok i'm very sorry to have confused you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give a proof by myself.

Proposition:
Let $G$ be a locally compact group and $\mu$ be a left haar measure on $G$. $f\in\mathscr{L}^1(G), g\in\mathscr{L}^\infty(G)$. Then $f*g$ is continuous. Obviously it is measurable.

Proof: Firstly, we suppose $f\in\mathscr{K}^\mathbb{C}(G)$ (Complex Compact support continuous function on $G$). Then similar to proposition 9.1.6 in Donald Cohn-Measure Theory-Second Edition, we get $\forall t_0\in G, \forall \epsilon >0, \exists A$ is the open neighborhood of $t_0$ such that $\forall t\in A$,
\begin{equation*}
\int |f(ts)-f(t_0s)|\,\mathrm{d}\mu(s)<\frac{\epsilon}{\|g\|_{L^\infty}+1}. 
\end{equation*}
Then
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
|f*g(t)-f*g(t_0)|&\le\int |f(ts)-f(t_0s)||g(s^{-1})|\,\mathrm{d}\mu(s)\\
&\le\|g\|_{L^\infty}\int |f(ts)-f(t_0s)|\,\mathrm{d}\mu(s)<\epsilon.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
Then $f*g$ is continuous.

Secondly, we prove the theorem. There exists $f_n\in\mathscr{K}^\mathbb{C}(G)$ such that $\|f_n-f\|_{L^1}\rightarrow 0$. Then $\forall t\in G$,
\begin{equation*}
|f_n*g(t)-f*g(t)|\le \|f_n-f\|_{L^1}\|g\|_{L^\infty}. 
\end{equation*}
Then $f_n*g$ converges to $f*g$ uniformly. Then $f*g$ is continuous.